# leaflet Js custom control button add (text, hover)

Tags: javascript, button, leaflet

I followed [this control-button-leaflet tutorial](http://www.coffeegnome.net/control-button-leaflet/) and it worked for me. Now I want to:

1. show some text when i hover over the button (like with the zoom buttons)
2. Change the color of the button when i hover over it
3. be able to write text inside the button instead of an image.

Here's the code:

```
    var customControl =  L.Control.extend({        
      options: {
        position: 'topleft'
      },

      onAdd: function (map) {
        var container = L.DomUtil.create('div', 'leaflet-bar leaflet-control leaflet-control-custom');

        container.style.backgroundColor = 'white';     
        container.style.backgroundImage = "url(http://t1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcR6FCUMW5bPn8C4PbKak2BJQQsmC-K9-mbYBeFZm1ZM2w2GRy40Ew)";
        container.style.backgroundSize = "30px 30px";
        container.style.width = '30px';
        container.style.height = '30px';

        container.onclick = function(){
          console.log('buttonClicked');
        }

        return container;
      }
    });

    var map;

    var readyState = function(e){
      map = new L.Map('map').setView([48.935, 18.14], 14);
      L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png').addTo(map);
      map.addControl(new customControl());
    }

    window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', readyState);
```

Comment: The link seems to be broken.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

It seems you more need a Button than a div:

```
    var container = L.DomUtil.create('input');
    container.type="button";
```

1. Then you can easily set a mouseover text:

   ```
   container.title="No cat";
   ```
2. And some Text instead of an image:

   ```
   container.value = "42";
   ```
3. And you can use the mouse events to style the button:

   ```
   container.onmouseover = function(){
     container.style.backgroundColor = 'pink'; 
   }
   container.onmouseout = function(){
     container.style.backgroundColor = 'white'; 
   }
   ```

(you could of course do this last part with css, might be more elegant)

Full example: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/oXVMvy

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/4wfrqm1k/ for anyone who can't see the Run option on codepen for some reason.